# Plotting a parametric function containing an integral

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I need to plot this expression

$$ \phi(s; H,B)=\left(\int_{0}^{s}\frac{1+B\ \sin2H\ t}{\sqrt{1+B^2+2B\sin2H\ t}} \text{d} t,\ \frac{1}{2H}\sqrt{1+B^2+2B\sin2H\ s}\right)$$

for $H=0.5$, $B=0, 0.5, 1, 1.5$, but I don't know how to write *Mathematica* code because I have never worked in *Mathematica* before.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sora, I'm afraid that this is not exactly what this forum is for. It would certainly help your case if you could show some beginning attempts at least, rather than just asking for somebody to do it all for you.

Comment: Here are some links to get you started: [Defining functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html), [integrating an expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html), [plotting a function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). Start with those and feel free to ask specific questions about how to use any of these functions or how to specifically do something in the Wolfram language. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you guys :) I will certainly study those links you provided Arnoud.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what range of $s$ you had in mind, so I arbitrarily chose one below. You should be able to change it at will.

This is an example in hopes that you will study this further and get to the point where you can come up with such code yourself. Please take a look at the excellent links provided by Arnoud as well to get you started.

```
Clear[phi]

phi[s_?NumericQ, h_, b_] :=
 {
  NIntegrate[(1 + b Sin[2 h t])/Sqrt[1 + b^2 + 2 b Sin[2 h t]], {t, 0, s}],
  1/(2 h) Sqrt[1 + b^2 + 2 b Sin[2 h s]]
 }

Table[
 ParametricPlot[phi[s, 0.5, b], {s, 0, 15}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],
 {b, {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

This is your function:

```
phi[s_, H_, B_] := 
 NIntegrate[(1 + B Sin[2 H t])/Sqrt[
   1 + B^2 + 2 B Sin[2 H t]], {t, 0, s}] 1/(2 H) Sqrt[
  1 + B^2 + 2 B Sin[2 H s]]
```

But if you want to plot it you have to give the value for s.

```
Plot[{phi[s, 0.5, 1], phi[s, 1, 1], phi[s, 1.5, 1], phi[s, 2, 1]}, {s, 0, 16}]
```

[image]

Comment: Fabian, I understood the OP's equations to be defining a point with $(x,y)$ coordinates, rather than being the product of two factors.

Comment: Oh yes that is also possible. ;)